# Terraform - Impossible to apply rights at the same time as creating groups

Tags: azure-active-directory, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I have to put a list of groups (var.dev) in the group 'cod-xxx01'.
My terraform creates all the groups and rights at the same time.

Is there a way to retrieve this list once the groups are created ? The 'depends_on' does not seem to work.

The problem is if groups in my variable "codeur" are not created, I have this error :

```
│ Error: Invalid index
│
│   on RightGroupMember.tf line 35, in resource "azuread_group_member" "Terra-Aad-Member-Con-Dev-Reader":
│   35:   group_object_id  = azuread_group.Terra-Aad-Group-Right["${var.dev[count.index]}"].object_id
│     ├────────────────
│     │ azuread_group.Terra-Aad-Group-Right is object with 65 attributes
│     │ count.index is 10
│     │ var.dev is list of string with 11 elements
│
│ The given key does not identify an element in this collection value.
```

My code is :

```
variable "dev" {
  type = list(string)
  default = [
    "rea-vma-dev01",
    "rea-vma-rec01",
    "rea-vma-pre04",
    "con-bql-dev01",
    "rea-bql-rec01",
    "rea-ins-dev01",
    "rea-ins-rec01",
    "rea-ins-pre04",
    "rea-rmq-dev01",
    "rea-rmq-rec01",
    "rea-rmq-pre04",
  ]

  description = "Access for 'cod-xxx01'"
}

resource "azuread_group_member" "Terra-Aad-Member-Con-Dev-Reader" {
  count = length(var.dev)

  group_object_id  = azuread_group.Terra-Aad-Group-Right["${var.dev[count.index]}"].object_id
  member_object_id = azuread_group.Terra-Aad-Group["cod-xxx01"].object_id

  depends_on = [
    azuread_group.Terra-Aad-Group-Right
  ]
}
```

Thank you so much.

---

The others resource are :
For groups :

```
Right_Groups = {for x in csvdecode(file("${path.module}/_RightGroups.csv")) : x.droits_groups => x.description}

resource "azuread_group" "Terra-Aad-Group-Right" {
  for_each = local.Right_Groups

  display_name     = lower(each.key)
  security_enabled = true
  description      = each.value
}
```

The CSV for 'Right_Groups' :

```
droits_groups,description
rea-vma-dev01,dev01
rea-vma-rec01,rec01
rea-vma-pre04,pre04
con-bql-dev01,dev01
rea-bql-rec01,rec01
rea-ins-dev01,dev01
rea-ins-rec01,rec01
rea-ins-pre04,pre04
rea-rmq-dev01,dev01
rea-rmq-rec01,rec01
rea-rmq-pre04,pre04
```

I think it has everything you need.

Comment: Can you add the other resource to the question as well? I'm guessing it was created with `for_each`?

Comment: I have added the others resources.

Comment: That will not work as one resource is using `for_each` and the other one is using `count`.

Answer (score 1):

What I would suggest here is using resource chaining with `for_each` [1]. So the `azuread_group` can remain as is, but you would have to change the `azuread_group_member` resource:

```
resource "azuread_group_member" "Terra-Aad-Member-Con-Dev-Reader" {
  for_each = azuread_group.Terra-Aad-Group-Right

  group_object_id  = each.value.object_id
  member_object_id = azuread_group.Terra-Aad-Group["cod-xxx01"].object_id
}
```

---

[1] https://www.terraform.io/language/meta-arguments/for_each#chaining-for_each-between-resources

Comment: Yes, this would be the ideal solution.
But what should I do if I add a new group and I don't want to have it in the 'cod-xxx01' group ?

Comment: That's a different topic altogether isn't it? :)

Comment: No. If, for example, I add this line to my CSV:

rea-rmq-pre05,pre05

And I don't want this new group to be in 'cod-xxx01' ?

Comment: Well, that wasn't the original question wasn't it?

Comment: Not necessarily the original question but it's the same subject.
But Ok.

Comment: We can go on like this as much as you like. But the question was how to fix the issue that you were having. My answer is supposed to help with that. As for the comments, you would have to come up with a way to reference the group value you want. So that could be done using variables (local or regular), you could create the groups `azuread_group.Terra-Aad-Group` using the same keys as for the `azuread_group.Terra-Aad-Group-Right` resource or find a way to map between the different sets of groups. The choice is yours.

Comment: Finally, I found it with the second option.

Comment: Great to hear that.